# jstree checking if no data returned by ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jstree

I'm building an application using jstree 3.2.1

My tree is rendered using an ajax request like this:

```
$("#jstree").jstree({
    "core" : 
    {
      'data' : 
      { 
        type: "POST",
        url : '/ajax.php',
        dataType : 'json'
      }
    },
    "plugins" : [ "search", "json_data" ]
});
```

The script, ajax.php, returns a json encoded array and this populates the tree fine.

But if there's no data returned by ajax.php (an empty array for example) how can I check this  and handle it appropriately, for example putting a message in `#jstree` to tell the user there is no data?

The ajax syntax looks strange to me, but the above code actually works in terms of getting the data via ajax. It looks odd because there's no `done()` or equivalent one might use in normal jquery where you could do a check on what was returned.

Answer (score 1):

To give myself flexibility, I create my own ajax call and put the JSON data into a variable, then pass this variable to the JSTree initialization. So, you could do something like this:

```
var jsTreejsonData = $.ajax({
    // Your Ajax here
});

if (jsTreejsonData)
{
    var jsTreeConfig = { 
        core: { 'data': jsTreejsonData },
        plugins: ['search']
    }

    $("#jstree").jstree(jsTreeConfig);
}
else
{
    //Blank response handling goes here
}
```